# How to apply multiple Klein-Gordon operators to products of propagators?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, propagator, s-matrix-theory, wick-theorem

I have the 4-point correlation function for a scalar free field
$$
\langle{0} | T \phi_1 \phi_2 \phi_3 \phi_4 | 0 \rangle = -\left[ \Delta_F(x_1-x_2) \Delta_F(x_3-x_4) + \Delta_F(x_1-x_3) \Delta_F(x_2-x_4) + \Delta_F(x_1-x_4) \Delta_F(x_2-x_3) \right].
$$

And I want to apply the corresponding 4 Klein-Gordon operators of the LSZ reduction formula to it
$$
(\square_4 + m^2) (\square_3 + m^2) (\square_2 + m^2) (\square_1 + m^2).
$$

Applying the first operator on the right, which acts on $x_1$ only, I would get the expression
$$
i\left[ \delta^{(4)}(x_1-x_2) \Delta_F(x_3-x_4) + \delta^{(4)}(x_1-x_3) \Delta_F(x_2-x_4) + \delta^{(4)}(x_1-x_4) \Delta_F(x_2-x_3) \right].
$$

But how can I proceed from here? I know that at the end of the LSZ formula I should get a bunch of momentum deltas, since this is a free theory and therefore I'm looking at the identity part of the $S$ matrix. However, I must be doing calculations in the wrong way between the Klein-Gordon operators and the resulting position delta functions, since I always end up getting $0$.